# How to put the user input in a array and go through the array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Im making a code that gets the user input and put then in descending order, but i need help in this part, to put the user input into a array, the much input the user make, only stopping when '-1' is typed.
Here is the code:

```
 int []vet = new int[]{};

for(int i = 0; i != -1;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("digite os valores");
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    vet[i] = input;

}
```

This code generates this error: "Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: Use `List<int>` instead to store user's input so that you won't have to worry about the index anymore. Plus, you declare an array of 0 length that is why you get this error. And your FOR loop is an infinite one cause `i != -1` will always be true and you'll never reach `-1`. You should avoid doing that.

Comment: If you need a container without fixed size, then use one. Arrays are fixed size. Also, i is going to be _always_ != -1 in your code. So you got yourself an infinite loop, there. But of course, trying to access an array index that out of bounds is going to throw. That means: fix those two things: 1. Use a list instead of an array 2. Fix your loop-ending-condition.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked, i improved my code, changed the array to a list and the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
List<int> vet = new List<int>();
int Response = 0;

Console.WriteLine("digite os valores");
Response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
vet.Add(Response);

while (Response != -1)
{
     Console.WriteLine("digite os valores");
     Response = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     vet.Add(Response);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed 2 major problems with your code.

A. you used an array for a dynamic sized list.
B. you used a for loop for an unknown amount of iterations.

The solution for problem A is, use a `List<int>` from the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` (important to import that)

For problem B you should use a while loop and check when an input variable is equals to -1, then close the loop.